# Dropdown menu doesn't dropdown on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
                            <li className={styles.link + " " + styles.hideOnMobile}>
                            <div className={styles.dropdownMenu}>
                                <button className={styles.dropbtn}>Product</button>
                                <div className={styles.dropdownContent}>
                                    <a
                                        href="#"
                                        onClick={this._trackClick.bind(this, "header")}
                                    >
                                        Link 1
                                    </a>
                                    <a
                                        href="#"
                                        onClick={this._trackClick.bind(this, "header")}
                                    >
                                        Link 2
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>


.dropdownMenu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {  
    padding: 14px 16px;     
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    &:hover{        
        background-color: $color-active-dark;
        cursor: pointer;
    }   
}

.dropdownContent {

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: $color-active-dark;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    &:hover {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    a {
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        &:hover{
            background-color: $color-active-dark;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code, currently it doesn't seem to change the display to block when I hover over it and I'm not sure why. It is suppose to be a dropdown menu on top nav bar where when I hover, Link 1 and Link 2 is suppose to dropdown, but right now when I hover, the product button changes color. I'm pretty new at front-end, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have some variables in html : `{styles.dropdownContent}`. You didn't attach it to your post. What does it render ?

Comment: I can't spot anywhere in your post the code that triggers opening drop-down menu. I guess, you might want to use some kind of [synthetic event](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) for that purpose, like `onMouseOver` or such.

Comment: @sonic What do you mean? I did attach the code for .dropdownContent.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I was following this W3 tutorial and for them, they didn't add any synthetic event and it seems to work. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: my bad, I didnt realize its reactjs

Comment: Rethink your css for `.dropdownContent`. How do you hover of an element that is `display:none` to turn it visible?

Comment: is there a missing closing curly brace in the css - from `.dropdownContent`?

Comment: @RamRaider, No, the format is just a little off.

Comment: @Thomas does &:hover{display:block} not make it visible on hover? I thought that was its function.

Comment: @gofish Yes, that's what it means, but how do you hover over something that is not there? Where do you need to move your cursor so that it is over the div that won't be rendered *(because that's what `display:none` means, don't render me)*?

Comment: @Thomas how come it works fine on this tutorial I was following? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: Because they don't hover over the hidden div.

Comment: @Thomas I think I get what you mean. So I added the visibility option, but it still doesnt seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra line (extra selector) to your css to open submenu on hover. In plain css:

```
.dropdownContent:hover,
.dropbtn:hover + div {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

You asked for the dropdown on the hover trigger. This is not the "toggle" mechanism for touchscreen because that has to be done with Javascript.

**update**

Your other question: How to toggle (open/close on click) the dropdown?

```
<script>
var Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn");
for (var i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++) {
  Buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var Divs = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdownContent");
    var Shown = (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("show"));
    for (var j = 0; j < Divs.length; j++) Divs[j].classList.remove("show");
    if (Shown) this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    else this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
  });
}
</script>
```

with the following extra css at the end of your current nav css

```
.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
}
.dropdownContent.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Ofcourse this Javascript will open only one dropdown at a time if you have a navigation with multiple `<li class="link hideOnMobile">` items.